# Refresh IconCache.db programmatically

Tags: winapi, icons, taskbar

I have a button for firefox.exe pinned. I changed the pinned icon via registry I set the path to a url:

1. I added `firefox.exe` folder to *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications\` and set it's value to `C:\Users\myUsername\Downloads\addon.ico`
2. I added `firefox.exe` folder to *HKEY_CURRENT_USER*: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications\` and set it's value to `C:\Users\myUsername\Downloads\addon.ico`

The icon at that path definitely exists.

However even though my icon is pinned for it doesn't take. I'm guessing I have to refresh the `IconCache.db` can you please recommend a way to do this with win api? Without restarting computer or program or logging off computer please is my hope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHCNF_IDLIST, nil, nil)
```

Or you could try this:

```
SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_UPDATEITEM, SHCNF_PATH, 'YourPinnedFileName', nil)
```

Comment: Hi Denis. Could you add an explanation into this post as to what these items do, and why you would choose one or the other? That might be helpful for future readers. Thanks!